# Variable methods in PHP

Tags: php, class, methods

I was looking at the [codebird-php git](https://github.com/jublonet/codebird-php) and noticed that the author has a way to detect methods that are not declared in the class itself. For example, he has

> $cb->statuses_homeTimeline();

which successfully executes, despite there not being a method called `statuses_homeTimeline()` in the Codebird class.

I've tried looking for information regarding this type of construction, but without knowing what it's called, I haven't found anything.

What is it generally called (I've googled all variations of "variable methods," "mapping methods," etc)? Are there arguments against its use? How does it (in principle) work?

Comment: You are looking for the "magic method" `__call`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a bunch of questions involving `__call` and things you can do with it, but nothing about what `__call` actually *is*.

PHP objects have a number of Magic Methods. The most well-known being `__construct`.

[`__call`](http://php.net/__call) is a magic method which gets called whenever you try and call a method that doesn't exist. It's sort of a "catch-all" for methods.

The technical term is "Method Overloading".

So when `$cb->statuses_homeTimeline()` is called, if that method does not exist, it will instead call
`$cb->__call("statuses_homeTimeline",array())`

Comment: This is freaking awesome. PHP never ceases to amaze me. Are there any reasons to _not_ use it?

Comment: It's a catch-all, so you need to be sure that whatever you receive is valid input. Other than that, not really.

Comment: @jboneca: There are plenty of reasons to not do it. Let's start with a counter-question: how exactly is `$cb->statuses_homeTimeline()` better than `$cb->whatever('statuses', 'homeTimeline')`? There's less typing, but is less typing "freaking awesome"? Of course, there are also reasons for it. As in all things, you must find a balance.

Comment: @Jon It seems to me that `__call()` is a built-in way of doing `$cb->whatever('statuses', 'homeTimeline')`. To me they seem synonymous with the exception that the former is ready-to-go.'

Comment: @jboneca: Suppose there are `whatever1`, ... `whatever20` methods. Does replacing all of them with `__call` sound like a good idea? What about 19 methods? 18? Obviously stuff is being put on the scales and at some indeterminate point it tips them.

Answer (score 1):

[`__call()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) magic method.  `__call()` is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.